# How do I define a dictionary that is stored inside a function?

Tags: python-2.7

Here's the error

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "important_page_numbers2.py", line 19, in 
>   print(dictionary['page_number0'])
>   NameError: name 'dictionary' is not defined
>
> ---
>
> (program exited with code: 1)
>
> Press any key to continue . . .

I'm trying to import a specific function from the posted code in another program. I don't want the program to execute completely because it also prints.

To remedy this, I separated the different actions into functions bc I know that in 2.7.15 you need to type the function name outside of the function for it to be used.

Basically, when I make the first dictionary a function, it doesn't work

```
list1=["pg38", "page62", "83", "86", "96", "126", "page210", "236", 
"page155", "page 324"]#Hey stack overflow,
# this part doesn't matter I just never removed it bc i might use it 
#later
def dicts():
dictionary={"page_number0":"pg38","description0":"Working with dictionaries",
 "page_number1":"page62", "description1":"Working with ranges",
  "page_number2":"83","description2":"If and else sattements",
   "page_number3":"86", "description3":"omitting the else block",
    "page_number4":"96", "description4":"working with dictionaries",
     "page_number5":"126","description5":"Using continue in a loop",
     "page_number6":"page155","description6":"Importing an entire module",
     "page_number6.1":"page189","description6.1":"Chapter 10, files and exceptions",
      "page_number7":"page210","description7":"Saving user generated data",
      "page_number8":"236","description8":"Installing pygame",
       "page_number9":"page 324","description9":"Matplotlib"}

dicts()
def print1():
print(dictionary['page_number0'])
print(dictionary['description0'])
print("\n")
print(dictionary['page_number1'])
print(dictionary['description1'])
print("\n")
print(dictionary['page_number2'])
print(dictionary['description2'])
print("\n")
print(dictionary['page_number3'])
print(dictionary['description3'])
print("\n") 
print(dictionary['page_number4'])
print(dictionary['description4'])
print("\n")
print(dictionary['page_number5'])
print(dictionary['description5'])
print("\n")
print(dictionary['page_number6'])
print(dictionary['description6'])
print("\n")
print(dictionary['page_number6.1'])
print(dictionary['description6.1'])
print("\n")
print(dictionary['page_number7'])
print(dictionary['description7'])
print("\n")     
print(dictionary['page_number8'])
print(dictionary['description8'])
print("\n")
print(dictionary['page_number9'])
print(dictionary['description9'])                           

print1()
```

I want to be able to call upon a specific function using from import without stopping the original file from printing when I compile it on it's own.

When I make the dictionary a function, python doesn't recognize it as defined when I then try to print.

Comment: Please fix your indentation.

Comment: IndentationError - is all I get from this code - please [edit] and fix.

Comment: you know you can call `print()` without args and you will get that newline for free (it is the default delimiter)

Answer (score 1):

You can't access variables that are only defined as local variables in a function from outside code. That's one of the points of functions, they have their own namespaces. There are a few ways to work around this.

A function can modify the global namespace of the module it's defined it. To assign a new variable in the global namsapce, you need to put a `global` statement inside the function. For example you could put `global dictionary` above your big dictionary definition, and it would work (the dictionary would be defined when the function is called).

But there's a downside to using global variables, and that's that you have to program the name of the variable you want to use directly into the function. If you want to be able to call the function twice, getting two separate dictionaries, you'll have a tricky time of it, as the second one will overwrite the first one.

So a better way to get data out of a function is to `return` it. The value you name after `return` in a function gets used as the value of the function call. So the caller can do their own assignment to whatever variable they want (perhaps one in a separate module, even). So consider adding `return dictionary` to your function, and using it by putting the call in an assignment statement: `foo = dicts()`.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a return statement in the `dicts()` functions and also an assignment statement.  That is where there is an undefined error.

Do something like this:

```
def dicts():
    return ({"page_number0":"pg38","description0":"Working with dictionaries",
     "page_number1":"page62", "description1":"Working with ranges",
      "page_number2":"83","description2":"If and else statements",
       "page_number3":"86", "description3":"omitting the else block",
        "page_number4":"96", "description4":"working with dictionaries",
         "page_number5":"126","description5":"Using continue in a loop",
         "page_number6":"page155","description6":"Importing an entire module",
         "page_number6.1":"page189","description6.1":"Chapter 10, files and exceptions",
          "page_number7":"page210","description7":"Saving user generated data",
          "page_number8":"236","description8":"Installing pygame",
           "page_number9":"page 324","description9":"Matplotlib"})

dictionary = dicts()
```

Comment: I'm new to stack and didn't see ur answer. Thanks!!!!!!! Seriously thanks, I would have ben lost.